# Simple Flask Application Not Working

Tags: python, rest, flask

I trained a machine learning model which I wanted to deploy as an app. I learnt that flask is especially suited for this.

I have two functions, get_data from the user of the web app and then, infer_results which prints the results of image type.

I am trying to set up flask for the above use case. I started by following this tutorial: https://sourcedexter.com/python-rest-api-flask/

What I did:

```
In [71]: app = Flask(__name__)

In [72]: @app.route("/me", methods=["GET"])
    ...: def get_results():
    ...:     return "Dummy Result"
```

And then,

```
In [73]: app.run(host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But all I get is:

[image]

I can't figure out what is going wrong? This is my main question.

On a sidenote, it would be really great if you could offer some advice or suggestion on : how should I go about building my app: I want to do in Python only. But then, how should I design the UI: where user can put his data and upload it? Is there a way to package all my code (the machine learning code + the user input/output) in a desktop application that user can download and run on his PC?

Comment: Try using a script instead of a shell, that might be a problem.

Comment: Also you should split your sidenote as an independent question.

Comment: You should go and check the flask documentation, particularly the quickstart http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)`

**Use**:

```
app.run(host="localhost", threaded=True)
```

Or Execute the below script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# index
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello"

# /me    
@app.route("/me", methods=["GET"])
def get_results():
    return "Dummy Result"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the packaging part, but you can use django or flask to show your ml data and examples.

Comment: one more thing, how should I put the home route in flask: I tried using: @app.route("/", methods=["GET"]) before a function and it didn't work. Thanks :)

Comment: Updated the above code, try using the script, It works fine.